# Capturing url parameter value and using that in a SPARQL query

Tags: java, sparql, rdf, owl

Scenario: The user selects an option and clicks submit. When clicked, the user is directed a new jsp page. The query should run and show results only the ones who listed under the selected option.

In the Results jsp I have code similar to this

```
String jobCategory = request.getParameter("jobCat");
```

How do I write a SPARQL query to filter using the jobCategory string variable. Thanks!

Comment: This is too broad, really. We don't know what your RDF dataset looks like or how this job-category is supposed to match to it. Generally speaking you'd either just inject the value into the query string (taking care against injection attacks), or you'd use something like, for example, the [RDF4J SparqlBuilder](http://docs.rdf4j.org/sparqlbuilder/) to compose your query. But what that query should look like exactly we can't tell you, since we don't know your dataset.

Comment: Yes, it's the same question with less information. Should be deleted by the TO.